# SQL Parameters within long String with VBNET

Tags: sql, vb.net, code-injection

i am trying to make my server injection proof, and have a log table where I store human readable events.
Is it possible to put a sql parameter within the Logtext string? In order to prevent any malicious input to come via the maliciousString?

```
Dim User as String = "busssard"
Dim Logtext As String = "User performed modification " & maliciousString
myCommand = sqlconnection.CreateCommand()
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Logging ([FK_User],[Change]) Values(@Username, '" & Logtext & "')"
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",User)
```

There are workarounds, but i would like not to change too much in the whole DB structure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `AddWithValue` at all. Use `Add` and ALWAYS specify the size for columns that have one. Do it for both your values. Let's say that `FK_User` is `varchar(50)` and `Change` is `nvarchar(max)`:

```vb
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Logging ([FK_User], [Change]) VALUES (@FK_User, @Change)"
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FK_User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Change", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = logText
```

Comment: Thanks, i just came to answer my own question, i guess i had a brainfart...
I actually use the following that also checks datatype, but removed it for simplicity: 
                                `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change", SQLFormat_forParameter(Logtext, SqlDbType.VarChar, MaxStringLength:=50))`